# Python3- print (readline()) returning empty lines

Tags: python, urllib, readline

I'm using the below code in an attempt to print 8 lines after a string that is found in the file result.txt. The script is definitely finding the string, but the print function returns 8 empty lines after the string is found, rather than the contents of the actual lines.

```
request = urllib.request.Request(websiteurl)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
fw = open('result1.txt', 'w')
fw.write(str(data))
fw.close()
with open('result1.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
                if 'DeMarco' in line:
                        for _ in range(8):
                                print (f.readline())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is working, but you may add the parameter end='' in print function to avoid the automatically added end of line:

```
print (f.readline(), end='')
```

Are you sure about your file content?
With 4 lines and this content file:

```
0
a DeMarco z
1
2
3
4
5
6
xDeMarcoPaul
A
B
DeMarco
C
D
E
F
```

And this script:

```
with open('result1.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if 'DeMarco' in line:
      for _ in range(4):
        print (f.readline(), end='')
```

I have this output:

```
1
2
3
4
A
B
DeMarco
C
```

But if in the 8 following lines, there is also a pattern DeMarco, it will not be detected because `f.readline()` moves the cursor.

Comment: @Marsa- The issue was actually that the file contains raw html which didn;t contain new lines and needed converting to text, my original code would have worked if I have used html2text. I have however used your suggestion additionally so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just read response result in tuples of lines. Your code should look like this:-

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(websiteurl)
data = response.read()
fw = open('result1.txt', 'w')
fw.write(str(data))
fw.close()
lines = tuple(open('result1.txt', 'r'))
for x in lines:
    if 'google' in x:
        for y in range(8):
            print(x)
```

Comment: The issue was actually that the file contains raw html and needed converting to text, my original code would have worked if I have used html2text.